# Wrap the text in Rmarkdown to pdf documents

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdf-generation, pdflatex

I don't know what is happening but I've tried multiple options.
Trying to use the

- tidy = TRUE
- changing the argument tidy = "styler".
- geometry argument adjusting left to big size. No change at all

I have already installed 'formatR'

This is my original data. Any suggestions would be welcome

```
---
title: "Inferencia estadística - UOC"
format: pdf
date: "2024-03-06"
output: pdf_document

---

Ejercicios

1.  El embolismo pulmonar es una condición relativamente común que necesita hospitalización y que a menudo ocurre en pacientes hospitalizados. La presión arterial menor de 90 mm HG es uno de los criterios importantes para diagnosticar esta condición. Supongamos que la sensibilidad del test es del 95% y la especificidad del test es del 75% y la prevalencia es del 20%.
    1.  Calcula el valor predictivo positivo del test.
    2.  Calcula el valor predictivo negativo del test.
    3.  Responde a las preguntas anteriores si la prevalencia fuera del 80%.





{r, tidy= TRUE}

# 1.- Cálculo del Valor Predictivo Positivo (PPV)

# Sensibilidad, especificidad y prevalencia
sensitivity <- 0.95
specificity <- 0.75
Prevalence <- 0.2

# Calcular PPV
PPV <- sensitivity * Prevalence / ((sensitivity * Prevalence) + ((1 - specificity) * (1 - Prevalence)))
PPV

# 2.- Cálculo del Valor Predictivo Negativo (NPV)

# Calcular NPV
NPV <- (specificity * (1 - Prevalence)) / (((1 - sensitivity) * Prevalence) + ((specificity) * (1 - Prevalence)))
NPV

# 3.- Ajuste de Prevalencia

# Nueva prevalencia
Prevalence <- 0.8

# PPV y NPV actualizados
PPV <- "93.8%"
NPV <- "78.94%"
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Could you please explain why your code is not working and what you expect?

Comment: I expect to get the text wrapped, the text in the chunks is exceeding the margins . Why is not working, no idea, because the pdf is rendered, but without the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some `tidy.opts` to make sure the code doesn't exceed the margins. Also make sure to sure ` to create a code chunk like this:

````
---
title: "Inferencia estadística - UOC"
format: pdf
date: "2024-03-06"
output: pdf_document
---

Ejercicios

1.  El embolismo pulmonar es una condición relativamente común que necesita hospitalización y que a menudo ocurre en pacientes hospitalizados. La presión arterial menor de 90 mm HG es uno de los criterios importantes para diagnosticar esta condición. Supongamos que la sensibilidad del test es del 95% y la especificidad del test es del 75% y la prevalencia es del 20%.
    1.  Calcula el valor predictivo positivo del test.
    2.  Calcula el valor predictivo negativo del test.
    3.  Responde a las preguntas anteriores si la prevalencia fuera del 80%.





```{r, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=50)}

# 1.- Cálculo del Valor Predictivo Positivo (PPV)

# Sensibilidad, especificidad y prevalencia
sensitivity <- 0.95
specificity <- 0.75
Prevalence <- 0.2

# Calcular PPV
PPV <- sensitivity * Prevalence / ((sensitivity * Prevalence) + ((1 - specificity) * (1 - Prevalence)))
PPV

# 2.- Cálculo del Valor Predictivo Negativo (NPV)

# Calcular NPV
NPV <- (specificity * (1 - Prevalence)) / (((1 - sensitivity) * Prevalence) + ((specificity) * (1 - Prevalence)))
NPV

# 3.- Ajuste de Prevalencia

# Nueva prevalencia
Prevalence <- 0.8

# PPV y NPV actualizados
PPV <- "93.8%"
NPV <- "78.94%"
```
````

Output:

[image]